# Parse string variables from Unix Shell into HiveQL

Tags: unix, hive

I have a shell script file which I parse both numeric and string variables. An example below:

**Shell Script**

```
hive --hiveconf time_1=34600 --hiveconf time_2=34588 --hiveconf message="hello_world" -f mytask.hql
```

Also I have a Hive query in the respective file 'mytask.hql' as follows:

**HiveQL file**

```
SELECT col1, col2, ${hiveconf:message} AS myMessage
FROM table1
WHERE trtime between ${hiveconf:time_1} and ${hiveconf:time_2};
```

The problem is that I want to have a column that contains the message "Hello world" or whatever the external - from Unix Shell Script - variable contains, in every line, but I got the following error:

> [Error 10004]: Line **xxx** Invalid table alias or column                                                                                                              reference 'hello_world': (possible column names are: col1, col2 ... (Etc.)

**The output that I want to have is something like this:**

[image]

Comment: try `hivevar` instead of `hiveconf` in the shell and call as `${message}` in the script

Comment: What does it say when you do `DESC table1` ?

Comment: are you using hive command line interface or Beeline?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala I use command line. The suggestion of '${hiveconf:message}' worked. Thank you!

Comment: @octano It described the table1, no problem for this table, it is used correctly. I found the solution in the problem using the '${hiveconf:message}'. Thank you!

Comment: @serge_k For the example I used as hql query it doesn't work. But, If I replace the ${hiveconf:message} with '${hiveconf:message}' it works fine. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

String constants in SQL should be quoted using single quotes: `'${hiveconf:message}'`:

```
SELECT col1, col2, '${hiveconf:message}' AS myMessage
FROM table1
WHERE trtime between ${hiveconf:time_1} and ${hiveconf:time_2};
```

And without quotes ${hiveconf:message} is resolved in hello_world, without quotes it looks like column, not a constant, this is why you got such exception.

Comment: If have an array, lets say:

names=("Nick" "Helen")

And I want to parse the first name from shell AND to use it in hiveql to create a table with the name mytable_'${hiveconf:names}', Could I use the same syntax?

Comment: @Vamkos it will work without quotes, and of course not with array, if you parse it in a shell as you said. You do not need quotes inside table_name.

Comment: I found that time_1 and time_2 are not parsed correctly into the HiveQL code. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Vamkos Testing it: `hive --hiveconf time_1=34600 --hiveconf time_2=34588` then in the hive: `hive> select ${hiveconf:time_1} as time_1, ${hiveconf:time_2} as time_2;
OK
34600   34588
Time taken: 2.101 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)`

Comment: @Vamkos So, it works as expected. Check your shell script, maybe it is some issue in it

Comment: @Lefjoin actually I use the ${hiveconf:time_1} and ${hiveconf:time_2} only in the where clause for filtering and I do not get rows back.

I tried to create the time2 as a calculation from t1 in the shell and then to parse it in hiveconf:

Example time2=$((time1-1)). Is this correct?

Comment: @Vamkos Calculate everything in shell and pass to hive. Print in the shell before executing Hive to make sure it works, also print in the Hive using ` ! echo ${hiveconf:time_1}` or just select: select ${hiveconf:time_1} as time_1, ${hiveconf:time_2} as time_2; to make sure it works. If you have question about how to do it in a shell, please create one more question about shell and post your script

Comment: you can find the new post here! I would appreciate your help!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53082120/parse-strings-in-hive-using-shell