# Parse Strings in HIVE using Shell

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop, hive

I have a shell script that I use to parse a string variable into Hive, in order to filter my observations. I provide both the script and the hive code below.

In the following script I have a variable which has a string value and I try to parse it into hive, the example below:

**Shell Script:**

```
name1='"Maria Nash"' *(I use a single quote first and then a double)*

hive --hiveconf name=${name1} -f t2.hql
```

**Hive code (t2.hql)**

```
create table db.mytable as

SELECT *

FROM db.employees

WHERE emp_name='${hivevar:name}';
```

**Conclusion**

To be accurate, the final table is created but it does not contain any observation. The employees table contains observations which has emp_name "Maria Nash" though.

I think that I might not parse the string correctly from shell or I do not follow the correct syntax on how I should handle the parsed variable in the hive query.

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: Why are you using single+ double quotes. Double quotes is enough. they will be removed when passed to Hive and in the Hive you added single quotes, this is correct. Or your emp_name contains double quotes?

Comment: @leftjoin Please check again my example. I changed it. I replaced the "Maria" with a string like "Maria Nash". It might be different.

Comment: quotes are processed by shell but when you are using the quotes inside quoted expression they are part of string value, you can use for example `name1='Maria Nash'` then `hive --hiveconf name="${name1}" -f t2.hql`, double quotes are important around parameter expansion, the issue is using `name=${name1}` without quotes

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul That's the correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: Add this as the first line in the Hive script: ` ! echo emp_name='${hivevar:name}'` - space+! is a shell command executed from Hive. This will prints your parameter

Answer (score 0):

you are passing variable in `hiveconf` namespace but in the sql script are using `hivevar`, you should also use `hiveconf`:

```
WHERE emp_name=${hiveconf:name} --hiveconf, not hivevar
```

Answer (score -1):

Use of the CLI is [deprecated](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli)

you can use beeline from a shell script

it should look something like

```
beeline << EOF

!connect jdbc:hive2://host:port/db username password

select * 
from db.employees
where emp_name = "${1}"

EOF
```

assuming that $1 is the input from the script.

This is an example of how to do it rather than a production implementation. Generally,

1. Kerberos would be enabled so username and password wouldn't be there
   and a valid token would be available
2. Validate the input parameters.

Given that you can do it in a single line

```
beeline -u jdbc:hive2://hostname:10000  -f {full Path to Script} --hivevar {variable}={value}
```

Comment: This is a SQL injection attack waiting to happen. You are not passing a value to a query; you are dynamically *constructing* a query from a variable, which could contain an arbitrary fragment of SQL.

Comment: changed it but still this generally depends on how you pass the parameters into the script

Comment: The problem is `where emp_name = "${1}"`. Suppose `$1` is `1; drop table db.employees`. The query seen by `beeline` is now `select * from db.employees where emp_name = 1; drop table db.employees`, not `select * from db.employees where emp_name = '1; drop table db.employees'`.

Comment: but that is true of any parameterised script without any field validation, i do understand what you mean but it does seem a little obtuse.  you could have improved my answer by adding in field validation.

Comment: The idea is that you don't construct the query in `bash`. I don't know what the capabilities of `beeline` are, but pretend you could call it like this: `beeline 'select * from db.employees where emp_name = %s' "$1"`. Now *you* are not constructing the query; you tell `beeline` to take the value of `$1` and insert it into the query where `%s` is, but *safely* so that you aren't mixing code and data.